# Sandisk SD Card (32GB) Corrupted - Recover Data (Photos) if drive is unmountable?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, photos, partition-recovery, file-corruption

I could really do with help recovering 500 or so photos from a corrupted SD Card.

I was out taking photos in Iceland on a 12-month old SanDisk SD card. Whilst writing photos to the card, I got the error message "Cannot create folder" on my Canon and was unable to continue taking photos.

Once in an SD Card Reader, the disk shows in Disk Utility with a partition. However, it will not mount. I receive the error (-69874) when performing 'First Aid' on the disk.

The disk shows as the full 30GB when in Disk Utility, and shows data on the card when the SD Card reader is in a Windows system.

The information for the card is as follows:

- Volume name : SBR1511624
- Volume type : Windows_FAT_32
- BSD device node : disk2s1
- Connection : USB
- Device tree path : IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/EHC2@1A
- Writable : No
- Is case-sensitive : No
- Volume capacity : 30,904,156,160
- Owners enabled : No
- Is encrypted : No
- Can be verified : No
- Can be repaired : No
- Bootable : No
- Journaled : No
- Disk number : 2
- Partition number : 1

Photos were stored in the RAW+JPEG file format.

I have tried EaseUS, DiskDrill and Photorec without success (just yet, anyway!). That said, I lack the knowledge to dig deeper or repair a partition to the card.

Any suggestions would be very, very welcome!

Comment: If you cannot find a way to mount the volume, then file recovery will not be possible, outside of a file recovery service which might have other tools at their disposal other then software.  All depends on the reason the card failed to begin with.

Comment: Which operating system do you use to mount the card? What error message do you get?

Comment: @muclux I am using MacOS High Sierra - trying to mount in Disk Utility. No error message. The Card is displayed as "Mass Storage Device" (Disk2). When I try to mount, it changes the name of the partition from "X" to Disk2s1 without mounting. Is there a way to force mount through Terminal? I have used the generic - mount dev/disk2s1 code.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you aware of a way to force mount the disk? If not, could this be a case of a damaged partition? Could I use Testdisk to identify the failure and repair?

Comment: Even though you said you tried it already, Photorec/testdisk would be my safest bet. To speed up the process (of trying to restore,mount, etc) and to make it safer, I would suggest working with a dd of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of luck with MiniTool Power data recovery. It skips all the mounting and partition stuff. If you can see your card in 'Disk Management' in whatever state, it should be sufficient. It just looks after signatures of JPGs (not sure about RAWs) and repairs those in the best way possible. However, it will strip of any metadata.